# Print an array without duplicates numbers in c++ - no set allowed - my source it's twisted?

Tags: c++, arrays

Like the title say i have to do an exercise where the user put in input some numbers and the objective it's to print them out without duplicates... I have written my source but maybe it's too much twisted and it's can be easily improved and simplified... In short i have done a for cicle that scan the positions in the array and a variable, called C, that save in memory the number. Then i have putted inside of it another for cicle that scan the array and if the c variable have the same value of the position checked a boolean flag become true (true=found a dupl.) and the variable c assume 0 as value. otherwise if flag mantain the false value a second array memorize in vet[i] position the value of c. 
set it's not allowed.
Here the code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int const l=6;
    int vet[l],vet2[l];
    int c,i,i2;
    bool flag=false;  //falso = non duplicato, vero = duplicato

    i=0;

    cout << "inserire i valori nell'array: " << endl;
    for (i=0;i<l;i++){
        cin >> vet[i];
    }

    for (i=0;i<l;i++){
        c=vet[i];
        for (i2=i+1;i2<l+1;i2++){
            if (c==vet[i2]){
                flag=true;
                c=0;
            }
            else if (flag){
                vet2[i]=c;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "stampa dei numeri senza duplicati: " <<endl;
    for (i=0;i<l;i++){
        cout << vet2[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Can you use `std::set`?

Comment: never used std::set at school...

Comment: I know this won't teach you anything, but you can do this with a std::unordered_set in O(n) time.

Comment: Re: std::set - might be a good time to learn.

Comment: (`std::set` will be `O(nlgn)`)

Comment: You can trivially do it in O(n) time without `std::unordered_set` too - and faster still - but since this is homework and, presumably, the OP can't leverage the standard library algorithms, suggesting them to him seems pointless.

Comment: Homework which amounts to an exercise in how to do something badly seems even more pointless. Students should be encouraged to learn and use the resources/libraries/objects at hand rather than reinventing the (square) wheel. To quote Greenspun's Tenth Law of Programming: "Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad-hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of Common Lisp". In this case one could replace "Common Lisp" with "the standard template library".

Comment: @BobJarvis - Not only is it an exercise in how to do something badly, the student who barely gets it to "work" is given an `A+` by the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments it sounds that a `std::set` might be useful here.
On the other hand you can do the same with arrays. But I would highly recommend to switch to `std::vector`. In general you should familiarize yourself with the STL. A solution could be this.

```
int main()
{
    int const l=6;
    std::vector<int> vet;
    for(int i=0; i<l ;i++)
    {
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        vet.push_back(val);
    }
    sort(vet.begin(), vet.end());
    vet.erase(unique(vet.begin(), vet.end() ), vet.end());

    for_each(vet.begin(), vet.end(), [](int i){
        cout << i << " ";});

    return 0;
}
```